# Extjs4 - Ajax Request : Url generation

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I need to set an ajax request with a generated url.

```
Ext.define('Cc.store.Absences', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'Cc.model.Absence',
  autoLoad: false,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url:  'person/user_id/absences', //I need a param to define user id 
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
});
```

I think I have to use Ext.data.Operation but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to dynamically generate an URL and assign it to the store, you can do it as follows:

```
store.getProxy().url = '/person/' + user_id +'/absences';
store.load(); // need to reload your store.
```

To pass as normal parameters (POST or GET methods), you can use the technique explained by Warung Nasi.

You can use `Ext.data.Operation` if you plan generate parameters automatically for sorting, filtering , grouping etc to your store's proxy. You can read about the possible parameters in [Ext.data.proxy.Ajax documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html). Refer the Url Generation sub heading.

Answer (score 3):

use `extraParams` [more info](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html)

```
Ext.define('Cc.store.Absences', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   model: 'Cc.model.Absence',
   autoLoad: false,
   proxy: {
     type: 'ajax',
     extraParams : {
        id : "123"
     },
     url:  'person/user_id/absences', //I need a param to define user id 
     reader: {
       type: 'json'
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: but with in my controller, what I have to do to change this param ?

Comment: In fact, this ajax call will return the absences of an user. I need to change the url called according to user.