# Ajax request to controller c #

Tags: ajax, c#-4.0, extjs4

How do to get a simple text and display it in an alert, via ajax with
ExtJS 4 from a controller in c #.

example:

```
//Server
public JsonResult simpleData(){
 var text = "simple data";
 return Json(text, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
public JsonResult simpleData(){
 var text = "simple data";
 return Json(text, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

must be :

```
public JsonResult simpleData(){
 var text = "simple data";
 return Json(new {data = text}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

for ajax in EXTJS 4 (maybe I'm wrong), read here: [Extjs4 - Ajax Request : Url generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056551/extjs4-ajax-request-url-generation)